# PostgreSQL multiple joins and subqueries

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

When I join many tables to aggregate results I encounter the following problems:

- Duplicate records, of which the intensity depends on the diversity within joined tables
- Slow performance, of which sorts are the most memory consuming tasks revealed by explain analyze

My question is very simple: I want to tell PostgreSQL to stop the query from being dynamic at some point by staging the select command in steps, making certain selection criteria static - rather than dynamic.

What has to be accomplished can best be described as follows:

- make a new table where I define the the most basic first level joins
- save these "static" results
- join the next level joins, and forget about any selection criteria that have happened in the step before that are no longer relevant for the next join
- iterate through these steps until all joins are applied

However, I don't want to make separate tables. I want to achieve this goal in just one query.

Is that really too much to ask for? I want to tell PostgreSQL, for example with sub-queries, that the possibilities are limited and that it shouldn't keep worrying about sorts and what not when the previous subquery is correct.

This is an example of the query:

```
select a.report_id, a.object_id, a.statement, b.datapoint_id, dp.aspect_id, dp.entity_identifier_id, dp.period_id, dp.aspect_value_selection_id, dp.effective_value, c.label, r.start_id_pos, r.start_id_neg
from "..statements" a
left join table_data_points b on a.object_id = b.object_id
left join data_point dp on b.datapoint_id = dp.datapoint_id
left join "...labels" c on dp.aspect_id = c.aspect_id and a.statement = c.statement
left join ".relationships" r on a.relationship_set_id = r.relationship_set_id and dp.aspect_id = r.from_id
where a.report_id=1 and c.label is not null
```

Explain analyze:

```
Merge Join  (cost=1151055.97..1198086.26 rows=3334642 width=200) (actual time=7295.864..7527.759 rows=178402 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: ((c.aspect_id = dp.aspect_id) AND ((c.statement)::text = (a.statement)::text))
  ->  Sort  (cost=94244.49..96166.99 rows=768997 width=34) (actual time=3772.495..3857.589 rows=381191 loops=1)
        Sort Key: c.aspect_id, c.statement
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 91433kB
        ->  Seq Scan on ...labels c  (cost=0.00..19064.97 rows=768997 width=34) (actual time=0.126..1851.052 rows=768511 loops=1)
              Filter: (label IS NOT NULL)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1056811.07..1057409.25 rows=239275 width=179) (actual time=3523.293..3540.153 rows=178163 loops=1)
        Sort Key: dp.aspect_id, a.statement
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 74kB
        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1028295.21..1035433.87 rows=239275 width=179) (actual time=3383.303..3522.908 rows=301 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: ((dp.aspect_id = r.from_id) AND (a.relationship_set_id = r.relationship_set_id))
              ->  Sort  (cost=896234.26..896832.45 rows=239275 width=75) (actual time=134.169..134.253 rows=289 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: dp.aspect_id, a.relationship_set_id
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 65kB
                    ->  Gather  (cost=1001.14..874857.06 rows=239275 width=75) (actual time=15.204..133.907 rows=289 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 1
                          Workers Launched: 1
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..849929.56 rows=140750 width=75) (actual time=0.056..34.625 rows=145 loops=2)
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..25680.40 rows=140750 width=35) (actual time=0.025..33.949 rows=145 loops=2)
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ..statements a  (cost=0.00..4150.51 rows=4 width=27) (actual time=0.012..33.840 rows=2 loops=2)
                                            Filter: (report_id = 1)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 116790
                                      ->  Index Scan using table_data_points_index04 on table_data_points b  (cost=0.57..5337.80 rows=4467 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.038 rows=72 loops=4)
                                            Index Cond: (object_id = a.object_id)
                                ->  Index Scan using data_point_pkey on data_point dp  (cost=0.57..5.85 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=289)
                                      Index Cond: (datapoint_id = b.datapoint_id)
              ->  Sort  (cost=132060.85..133822.38 rows=704613 width=128) (actual time=3249.054..3354.045 rows=264922 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: r.from_id, r.relationship_set_id
                    Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 82536kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on .relationships r  (cost=0.00..63620.13 rows=704613 width=128) (actual time=0.059..1005.916 rows=704415 loops=1)
Planning time: 47.995 ms
Execution time: 7565.196 ms
```

Comment: "*make a new table where I define the the most basic first level joins*" - could be achieved with a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). The sort is a result of the optimizers choice to use a Merge Join (which requires a sorted input). Indexes on `".relationship"(from_id, relationship_set_id)` and `"..statements"(relaltionship_set_id)` and `"...labels"(aspect_id, statement)` might help

Comment: thank you @a_horse_with_no_name